# update view controller data every 100 sec from web service

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization

i am implementing web service that sends data to my iphone. my iphone should ask web service for new data every 100 second. where is the best method to call the web service every 100 second ?

can you advice me for this issue ?

Comment: Does `NSTimer` sound like a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 'NSTimer'

```
 NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:100.0 target: self
                               selector: @selector(callAfterHundredSecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 100.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void)callAfterHundredSecond:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    NSLog(@"webServiceCalledAfter100sec");
}
```

Comment: where should i use this timer? my application has several view controllers i want the update to be done where ever the user is not just in the controller of these data

Comment: have never tried but you can try it : put this method into AppDelegate.m and put it into 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' this method and just see that if you navigate to some other viewController does it still log the 'webServiceCalledAfter100sec' into console? if yes then your problem will be solved i think it does so just test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your webservice and receive its data in background thread along with Timer which should run in foreground thread. Then you can sync between those methods with flag or whatever you wish. In this way your web service send response according to timer you set.

Answer (score 0):

I had a kinda same scenario but for me availability of web service during the web service call was kinda critical so what I came up with was to use push notification for IOS/Android to keep pushing notification every 5 minutes, on notification received I was doing my calls and stuff this way I know that web service is up and running, my user is a in a range of 3G/WIFI. Since I was doing this for two way synchronization without user interaction and the users are mostly in remote area where there is no much internet available. At the mean time I use notification for some other stuff too, so thought I can use it here too. dont know it is a good idea but it really work well on over 100 devices.